# PHP launching PowerPoint on server

Tags: php, xampp, powerpoint

```
echo "C:/DATA/SLIDES/" . date("l") . ".pps";
$openPowerPoint = "POWERPNT.EXE /S C:\\DATA\\SLIDES\\" . date("l") . ".pps";
system($openPowerPoint);
```

The browser appears to be waiting and nothing happens on the server. Am I doing something wrong?

The file is called Monday.pps

UPDATE --

I can run this code

```
$runCommand = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\shutdown.exe /r /t 5 /c \"The system is being updated\"";
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$output = $WshShell->Exec($runCommand)->StdOut->ReadAll;
echo "<p>$output</p>";
```

Please any help with launching powerpoint is appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, I want PowerPoint opened on the Server (not the client).

Comment: Yes. You can't just arbitrarily be launching programs on a server from a client endpoint. Think of the security implications!

Comment: unless the webserver service is allowed to interact with the desktop, it can't open windows, meaning you can't open powerpoint

Comment: Maybe it is... if it were, you wouldn't see anything in your browser.

Comment: The server is 2 feet away and I did walk over to check. It doesn't launch PowerPoint

Comment: Maybe whatever user PHP is running as doesn't have permissions to launch PowerPoint.

Comment: Why would it launch powerpoint on a remote server when you are referencing a local file?

Comment: I have a feeling that Marc B is probably onto it where powerpoint might want to launch but not have access to the desktop.

Comment: For starters - you will have to start Powerpoint, too (The application). Like `"c:\program files\microsoft office\office12\POWERPNT.exe" /O File name1.pptx` I can start soffice on my Linux machine with php and a X-Window system... Maybe on windows, too.

Comment: PowerPoint 2003 is installed. I even added the file path to the environment variables so I can open PowerPoint by typing POWERPNT.EXE /S C:\DATA\SLIDES\Monday.pps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System does only work with executeable files. On a windows system, `.pps` are not executeable per default.

Try by using the [`start` command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html), either alone or in combination with the [`cmd` command](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) so to allow to span a new shell and make PHP able to continue.